# Copying data into differently named columns in another SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I want to copy data from one table into another table where the columns have different names, and am trying to use the following

```
SELECT `content` AS `name`, `id` AS `orig_id` 
INTO `songs`
FROM `items` 
WHERE `categories` LIKE "%30%"
```

It doesn't work. How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean, exactly?  Were there error messages?  Was there unexpected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the columns of the destination table as part of the INSERT syntax as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO songs
    (name, orig_id)
    SELECT content, id
        FROM items
        WHERE categories LIKE '%30%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL :

```
select 
    name as cus, activator as act 
into dbo.pc1
from dbo.Pc
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT INTO` is T-SQL syntax.

For MySQL you'd use:

```
CREATE TABLE songs 
SELECT 
  content AS name
  , id AS orig_id 
FROM items 
WHERE categories LIKE '%30%'
```